# ¿Como puedo sumar horas y minutos?

Tags: php, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Lo que busco es mediante un botón que al darle clic me sume las horas y minutos de cada registro y aparezca su total en un campo, este script lo único que esta haciendo es realizarme la consulta de las horas pero no se como sumarlas.

```
<?php 
echo "<body>";
$id = $_POST['id'];

$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");

$query = "SELECT servicio_No, movil, despacho, salida, llegada_Origen, salida_Origen, llegada_Destino1, salida_Destino1, llegada_Destino2, salida_Destino2, disponible FROM servicio WHERE servicio_No = ?";

/*Prepara la setencia SQl para su ejecucion*/
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $query)) {

    /*Agrega variables a una sentencia preparada como parametros*/
    /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
    /*IMPORTANTE: Si id no es numérico en la base de datos, cambia la i por una s*/
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);

    /* Ejecuta una consulta preparada */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /*Se transfiere los  resultados de la ultima consulta*/
    $stmt->store_result();

    /* Vincula las variables a una setencia preparada para el almacenamineto de result */
    $stmt->bind_result($servicio_No, $movil, $despacho, $salida, $llegada_Origen, $salida_Origen, $llegada_Destino1, $salida_Destino1, $llegada_Destino2, $salida_Destino2, $disponible);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "
    <body class='body'>
    <center>
    <h1>Modificar tiempos</h1><br><br>
    <form method='POST' action = 'modificandoTiempos.php'>
    <label>Numero del servicio</label><br>
    <input type='int' name='servicio_No' value='".$servicio_No."'>

    <br><br>

    <label>Movil</label><br>
    <input type='int' name='movil' value='".$movil."'>

    </center>
    <center>

        <br>

        <input type='text' name='despacho' value='".$despacho."' placeholder='1.Despacho'>
        <input type='text' name='salida' value='".$salida."' placeholder='2.Salida'>
        <input type='text' name='llegada_Origen' value='".$llegada_Origen."'  placeholder='3.Llegada Origen'></br>
        <br><input type='text' name='salida_Origen' value='".$salida_Origen."' placeholder='4.Salida Origen'>
        <input type='text' name='llegada_Destino1' value='".$llegada_Destino1."' placeholder='5.Llegada Destino 1'>
        <input type='text' name='salida_Destino1' value='".$salida_Destino1."' placeholder='6.Salida Destino 1'></br>
        <br><input type='text' name='llegada_Destino2' value='".$llegada_Destino2."' placeholder='7.Llegada Destino 2'>
        <input type='text' name='salida_Destino2' value='".$salida_Destino2."' placeholder='8.Salida Destino 2'>
        <input type='text' name='disponible' value='".$disponible."' placeholder='9.Disponible'>

        <br><br>        

         <input type='submit' name='' value='Actualizar'>

         <input type='button' value='Volver de donde viniste!' onclick='history.back(-2)' class='submit'/> 
        </center>
        </form>
          ";
    } 
}

?>
```

Comment: No nos estas diciendo que campos son de fechas.
Deberias decir cuales son y deberias remarcar si hay una fecha de inicio y una de fin, por ejemplo.
En todo caso podrias usas la funcion TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, fechainicio, fechafin) en MySQL o DATEDIFF(minute, fechainicio, fechafin) en SQL Server para obtener los minutos que hay entre 2 fechas, acumular este valor en una variable y luego hacer la conversion de minutos a horas en php

Comment: En este caso no necesito la fecha ya que cada registro esta asociado a un id con sus horas respectivas

Comment: ¿Puedes aportar un ejemplo de los datos y de lo que deseas obtener? Realmente no esta claro lo que tienes y lo que buscas. Tal y como esta planteada la pregunta es dificil proporcionar una respuesta certera.

Comment: yon estoy ingresando los horas en la base datos este script me realizando la consulta y me esta mostrando las horas registradas

Comment: ahora lo que busca es poder sumar estas horas y minutos y sacar un total.

Comment: Seria mas facil si aportaras un ejemplo de los datos. Entiendo que buscas algo como lo que se plantea en esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66691/suma-php-mysql-session-start/66765#66765

Comment: si es algo parecido

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/100239)

Comment: Me quede esperando que aportaras mas datos para darte una respuesta mas concreta, en cualquier caso te dejo una respuesta que puedes adaptar.

Comment: Para tu caso en particular, te recomiendo no hacer el cáculo de las horas en el servidor sino enviar el rango de fechas al cliente por medio de tu APIREST y en el front hacer la resta de las horas, eso lo puedes hacer con la lib Moment.js, te dejo el link: https://momentjs.com/ A partir de allí tienes que tomar las fechas, las conviertes a fechas de tipo moment, las restas y eso te devuelve un objeto de tipo duración, el cual nuevamente tienes que convertir a uno tipo moment y allí ya puedes obtener el intérvalo de tiempo. Acá te puedes encontrar un más info: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durati

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expongamos un caso practico para listar los registros de la base de datos asi como generar un total de uno de los campos de tipo `TIME` mediante PHP.

Supongamos que tenemos en la base de datos una tabla como la siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM docs;

| id | user    | tiempo   |
|----|---------|----------|
|  1 |       1 | 10:22:51 |
|  2 |       1 | 05:21:09 |
|  3 |       2 | 01:02:15 |
|  4 |       3 | 23:10:01 |
```

Podriamos utilizar la [función `TIME_TO_SEC` de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) para que nos retorne el tiempo en segundos y así tener un valor acorde con el que poder hacer operaciones en PHP, ejemplo:

```
SELECT a.id, a.user, TIME_TO_SEC(a.tiempo) tiempo_segundos
FROM `docs` a;

| id | user | tiempo_segundos |
|----|------|-----------------|
|  1 |    1 |           37371 |
|  2 |    1 |           19269 |
|  3 |    2 |            3735 |
|  4 |    3 |           83401 |
```

Si queremos obrener el tiempo total en segundos podriamo hacer un `SUM` directamente en Mysql, ejemplo:

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(a.tiempo)) total_segundos 
FROM `docs` a;

| total_segundos |
|----------------|
|         143776 |
```

---

En php si queremos mostrar los registros y sumar a la vez podemos hacer lo siguiente por ejemplo, codigo comentado:

> Primero creamos una función para pasar de segundos a días, horas, minutos, segundos y dar formato, luego simplemente vamos sumando los tiempos en segundos para una vez tengamos el total de segundos pasarle el valor a la función.

```
<?php
// Declarmos una función para formatear de segundos a días, horas, minutos, segundos
function seg_a_dhms($seg) {
    $d = floor($seg / 86400);
    $h = floor(($seg - ($d * 86400)) / 3600);
    $m = floor(($seg - ($d * 86400) - ($h * 3600)) / 60);
    $s = $seg % 60;
    return "$d días, $h horas, $m minutos, $s segundos";
}



// conexión
$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "user","pass","database");
// query
$query = "SELECT a.id, a.user, TIME_TO_SEC(a.tiempo) tiempo_segundos, a.tiempo
FROM `docs` a;";

// preparar consulta
if ($stmt = $conexion->prepare($query)) {
    // ejecutar consulta
    $stmt->execute();
    //recuperar resultados
    $stmt->store_result();
    // Vincular resultados a variables
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $user, $tiempo_segundos, $tiempo);

    // Declaramos una variable para sumar el tiempo
    $total_tiempo_sec = 0; 
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        // mostramos lo que necesitemos
        echo 'El registro '.$id.' del usuario '.$user.' tiene un tiempo de '.$tiempo;
        // vamos acumolando la suma de los tiempos en segundos
        $total_tiempo_sec += $tiempo_segundos;
    }

    // una vez que finalice el while solo nos falta dar formato 
    // al total de tiempo con la función que declaramos al principio
    echo seg_a_dhms($total_tiempo_sec); // 1 Días, 15 horas, 56 minutos, 16 segundos
}
```

Comment: tu respuesta me ayudo mucho pero mira te muestro mi base de datos

Comment: tengo estas columnas y todas guardan tiempos y necesito sumarlas:

Comment: @CristianAntonioTrujilloGris Edita tu pregunta y utiliza el icono de imagen, en cualquier caso siempre prefiero texto a imagenes.

Comment: ya viste la imagen?

Comment: esto es lo que me muestra y el resultado no es correcto? El registro 1 del usuario Seguros De Vida Suramericana tiene un tiempo de 07 horas, 0 minutos

Comment: Si acabo de ver la imagen, pero tuve que rechazar la edicion que hiciste de mi respuesta, me referia a que editases tu pregunta. En cualquier caso seria facil adaptar el codigo que te pase. Haz un `SHOW CREATE TABLE nombre_tabla` a tu tabla y añadelo a tu respuesta, junto con algunos datos de ejemplo para hacer pruebas

Comment: no te entiendo en que parte del codigo tengo que añadirlo

Comment: edite el codigo por el que se adapto.

Comment: @CristianAntonioTrujilloGris Le escribi por el chat, continuemos por alli si le parece para no alargar mas los comentarios

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78153/discussion-between-cristian-antonio-trujillo-gris-and-xerif).

Comment: apenas estoy analizando si tu ayuda la puedo adaptar a lo que necesito me puedes ayudar con algo mas?

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien lo que quieres, puedes obtener los minutos de diferencia en cada paso en la propia query en `mysql`, por ejemplo suponiendo que tus campos de salida y llegada son tipo `datetime`:

```
$query = "SELECT servicio_No, movil, despacho, salida, llegada_Origen, salida_Origen, llegada_Destino1, salida_Destino1, llegada_Destino2, salida_Destino2, disponible 
, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, 'salida', 'llegada_Origen') as tiempo1
, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, 'salida_Origen', 'llegada_Destino1') as tiempo2
,....
FROM servicio WHERE servicio_No = ?"
```

Luego sólo tienes que sumar los minutos de los tramos que quieras y convertirlos a horas dividiendo el total de minutos por 60. De este modo tienes el cálculo directamente desde la consulta y lo puedes mostrar en el mismo momento que rellenas los datos. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: el formato que estoy utilizando es time

Comment: Para que Timestampdiff funcione requiere datetime, puedes añadirle delante el día desde php 'TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '"date(Y-m-d) ".salida', ''"date(Y-m-d) ".llegada_Origen') as tiempo1 por ejemplo. Como consejo, es mejor si puedes usar datetime por si un trayecto empieza en un día y acaba en el siguiente.

Comment: pero necesito mostralas en un campo

Comment: Añade tiempo1, tiempo2, ... como variables en el bind result, sumas el resultado en una variable php dentro del while y los muestras por ejemplo como un párrafo o como un input text readonly para que no sea modificable, y ya lo tienes.

Comment: no me funciona como me dices