# Error de horas y dias con funcion time

Tags: php

Estoy usando una funcion `time ago` pero me da un error de 3 horas y dias. Los dias y horas los guardo en este formato: `m/d/Y h:m`.

Este es el codigo

```
<?php
function humanTiming ($time) {
$time = time() - $time;
$time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
$tokens = array (
    31536000 => 'year',
    2592000 => 'month',
    604800 => 'week',
    86400 => 'day',
    3600 => 'hour',
    60 => 'minute',
    1 => 'second'
    );

foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
    if ($time < $unit) continue;
    $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
    return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s ago':'');
}
}
?>
<?=humanTiming(strtotime($row['fecha']));?>
```

El problema es que suma tres horas y se la fecha es `03/01/2019` toma como una semana y el dato fua agregado el dia de pero a las 00:00, da como resultado `hace tres horas` y no 1 hora 30 minutos.

pd: en Argentina es la hora 01:29 AM

Comment: No queda claro que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente, no se si quieres sumarle una cantidad de tiempo a una fecha dada o saber la diferencia de tiempo entre 2 fechas, revisa esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168407/como-puedo-sumar-horas-y-minutos/168547#168547 y la clase DateTime de php.

Comment: Hola y gracias, el texto final dice: _"El problema es que suma tres horas y se la fecha es 03/01/2019 toma como una semana y el dato fua agregado el dia de pero a las 00:00, da como resultado hace tres horas y no 1 hora 30 minutos."_ Cuendo digo que los dias los "guardo", significa que que el dato fecha esta guardado en la base de datos en el formato que aclare y por ultimo digo que el problema es que me suma (referido a la fecha guardada) 3 horas. Ese es el problema de la funcion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no se que es lo que quieres conseguir exactamente. Tampoco entiendo bien cual es el problema. Pero me imagino que lo que quieres es una función que pasandole una cantidad "X" en segundos, te devuelva algo del estilo : "a" años, "b" meses, "c" semanas, "d" dias, siendo estos el tiempo total en "lenguaje humano" de los segundos que le has pasado.

Si esto es lo que quieres, tu enfoque no es muy correcto ya que no alteras el tiempo que ya has calculado.

Es decir, algo asi deberia ser:

```
<?php
function humanTiming ($time) {
    $time = time() - $time;
    $time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
        );
    $result = '';

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        $time -= $unit*$numberOfUnits;
        $result .= $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?' ':' ');
    }
    return $result."'s ago";
}

echo "<br>".humanTiming(time() -  3721);
?>
```

Comment: Gracias y lo vuelvo a repetir. El texto final dice: _"El problema es que suma tres horas y se la fecha es 03/01/2019 toma como una semana y el dato fua agregado el dia de pero a las 00:00, da como resultado hace tres horas y no 1 hora 30 minutos."_ Cuendo digo que los dias los "guardo", significa que que el dato fecha esta guardado en la base de datos en el formato que aclare y por ultimo digo que el problema es que me suma (referido a la fecha guardada) 3 horas. Ese es el problema de la funcion.

Comment: Debajo del tento agregue los siguiente: `<?=humanTiming(strtotime($row['fecha']));?>`, llamo a la funcion, le paso los datos que guarde en la base de datos y EL PROBLEMA ES QUE ME SUMA 3 HORAS.  Lo que trato de hacer es que si la publicacion se hice hace una hora, que la funcion lo indique asi o hace una semana o hace un mes o hace un año. Espero quede claro!

Comment: El problema de las horas que añade o quita, suele suceder por diferencia de las zonas horarias que considera el programa y la base de datos. Por ejemplo si estas corriendo en un servidor en Argentina como dices que es GTM-3 y en la base de datos la fecha esta en UTC, entonces te dara siempre estas 3 horas de diferencia, UTC = GTM 0 o tambien llamada hora Zulu. De eso pueden venir los problemas, verifica la configuración de tu base de datos y si esta en UTC prueba forzar PHP para usar UTC puedes hacerlo con gmdate. Espero con esto lo soluciones.

Comment: Por cierto, como tienes guardada la fecha en tu base de datos ? Como date o como datetime?

Comment: Correcto, es la zona horaria, si bien esta guardada para cada usuario, no la estaba llamando... por eso el problema. Gracias